# Is Trojan:Win32/Tilken.B!cl a real threat? Trojan horse on geth files

Tags: go-ethereum, security, windows

Windows Defender accused some geth and ethereum files to have a trojan horse called **Tilken.B!cl**

```
file: C:\Program Files\Geth\uninstall.exe
file: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Geth\Uninstall.lnk
regkey: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CURRENTVERSION\UNINSTALL\Ethereum Geth
startup: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Geth\Uninstall.lnk
uninstall: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CURRENTVERSION\UNINSTALL\Ethereum Geth
```

Is it a false positive or a real threat??

Apparently this alert happened to more people:
[Is my computer infected? Trojan:Win32/Tilken.B!c...](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/7fswrp/is_my_computer_infected_trojanwin32tilkenbcl/)

Microsoft Malware Encyclopedia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most recent version of the client (1.7.3) for which Windows Defender raises the "Trojan:Win32/Tilken.B!cl" flag, VirusTotal reports 6 out of 67 detections: https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/aa95f8f9f4308827bfb5bd27e55762f78b5f370695c1954eef9462ec007864e0/detection. However, a very similar picture [was before](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/fa28fee8584d054694f58d4a00e7d72ffe303eadd821d7f46bbf31020bb3e1e6/analysis/1469454668/) with such clients.

I've found that the previous version of the client (1.5.5) also raised such a flag, but in reality, it seems to be clear as confirmed by Microsoft: see [related thread on GitHub](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2860). I've also submitted the analysis request for the v1.7.3 with potential "Trojan:Win32/Tilken.B!cl", will see the result.

**UPDATE 2017-12-04**

The submission to Windows Defender SI didn't confirm any malware in file contents, as shown on the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Cool! As soon as you have the analysi results, post it here. Might help more people.

Comment: @Guilherme Flores see the screenshot attached

Answer (score 0):

If you upload the file to here > Virus Total https://www.virustotal.com/#/home/upload

You will get a report which is accurate.

Comment: Without the binary myself I cannot say for sure but uploading it to Virus Total will confirm.

Comment: Windows defender removed the files earlier, I can't upload to virustotal, but thanks for the answers.